# Inno Setup Ideal Compression Speed

Tags: inno-setup

I'm new to this forum, and the reason I join is because out of curiosity I'm wondering how fast inno setup compression in other people's computer.

My speed while compressing using lzma2/ultra 64 is around 1.5 - 2.0 MB/s while I got the same speed when I'm just storing folder with different kind of file totaling in 150 GB (no compression / compresion = none).

My question: If I'm upgrading to (lets say) Intel Core i9 9900K, does it really increase the compression speed ?

My spec: 16 GB Ram, Intel i5-4690 with Windows 10 Pro

Thank you

Comment: Did you check Task Manager to see what resource throttles the compilation? If it is the CPU or a disk? (as you claim that *storing* is not faster).

Comment: Ya, my ram is 16 GB, during the compilation its only use ~ 11 GB Ram. CPU already maxed out at 100%.